# Determinar si una matriz puede dividirse en dos tal que tenga el mismo numero de caracteres especiales

Tags: c++, algoritmos

El siguiente código busca determinar si una matriz de tamaño N, compuesta de caracteres "." y "#" puede partirse en dos, tal que el numero de caracteres "#" en cada pieza sea el mismo. La partición debe hacerse de forma horizontal o vertical, no se puede diagonal ni en zigzag. Si esto se puede hacer, devuelve "YES" de lo contrario "No". La entrada se compone de un numero T que sera el numero de casos a evaluar, el numero N que es el tamaño de la matriz y finalmente la matriz. Por ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este fue el intento de solucion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int T, N, ca = 0, fa = 0, cd, fd, l, j, k, i;
    bool oso = 0;

    cin >> T;
    for (i = 0; i < T; ++i) {
        cin >> N;
        char cho[N][N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            scanf("%s", cho[i]);
        int col[N] = { 0 };
        int fil[N] = { 0 };
        for (k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
            for (j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
                if ((cho[k][j] == '#') && (cho[j][k] == '#')) {
                    col[j] += 1;
                    fil[j] += 1;
                } else if (cho[j][k] == '#') {
                    fil[j] += 1;
                } else if (cho[k][j] == '#') {
                    col[j] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        for (j = 1; j < N; ++j) {
            cd = 0;
            fd = 0;
            ca += col[j - 1];
            fa += fil[j - 1];
            for (l = N - 1; l >= j; --l) {
                cd += col[l];
                fd += fil[l];
            }
            if ((ca == cd) || (fa == fd)) {
                oso = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (oso == 1)
            cout << "YES" << endl;
        else
            cout << "NO" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

No obstante, noto que el codigo no detecta los casos en que no sirve. ¿Qué parte del codigo podría estar fallando?¿qué me recomiendan?

Comment: ¿Cómo se tienen en cuenta las tablas con columnas impares?

Answer (score 2):

Esto, una vez que le cogemos el *truco*, es mas fácil de lo que parece.

Para divisiones verticales, la lógica es simple: ir contando `'#'` **de fila en fila**, e ir acumulandolo.

Si al llegar a la última columna de una fila llevamos **exactamente la mitad** de símbolos ´#´, es posible dividir de forma vertical.

Esto, al mismo tiempo, nos da la clave para acelerar el proceso. Solo tenemos que contar **hasta que lleguemos a la mitad del total de `#`**. En tus 2 casos de prueba, podemos parar de contar al llegar a 5 `#`.

Los mismo es aplicable a divisiones horizontal; pero, en este caso, vamos acumulando *columna a columna*. Si al terminar una columna llevamos la mitad, la división es posible.

Bueno, al grano:

```
#include <iostream>

bool testVertical( const char *buff, int size, int count ) {
  int subtotal = 0;
  int lamitad = count / 2;

  for( int idx = 0; idx < ( size * size ); ++idx ) {
      if( idx && ( !( idx % size ) ) ) {
        if( subtotal == lamitad ) return true;
        if( subtotal > lamitad ) return false;
      }

      if( buff[idx] == '#' ) ++subtotal;
  }
  return false;
}

bool testHorizontal( const char *buff, int size, int count ) {
  int subtotal = 0;
  int lamitad = count / 2;

  for( int col = 0; col < size; ++col ) {
    if( subtotal == lamitad ) return true;
    if( subtotal > lamitad ) return false;

    for( int fila = 0; fila < size; ++fila ) if( buff[col + (fila * size)] == '#' ) ++subtotal;
  }

  return false;
}

int main( ) {
  int cases;

  std::cin >> cases;

  for( int n = 0; n < cases; ++n ) {
    int size;

    std::cin >> size;

    int count = 0;
    char *matrix = new char[size * size];
    char *idx = matrix;

    for( int curr = 0; curr < ( size * size ); ++curr ) {
      char simb[2] = { 0 };

      std::cin >> simb;
      *idx = simb[0];
      ++idx;
      if( simb[0] == '#' ) ++count ;
    }
    *idx = 0;

    // Casos especiales.
    // Todo #, ninguna #
    if( ( !count ) || ( count == ( size * size ) ) ) {
      std::cout << "YES";
      delete[] matrix;
      continue;
    }

    // El número de # es impar.
    if( count & 1 ) {
      std::cout << "NO";
      delete[] matrix;
      continue;
    }

    // Tenemos que calcularlo.
    if( testVertical( matrix, size, count ) ) std::cout << "Vertical: YES\n";
    if( testHorizontal( matrix, size, count ) ) std::cout << "Horizontal: YES\n";

    delete[] matrix;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Podríamos usar RAII para ahorrarnos las 3 llamadas a `delte[]`, e incluso intentar reutilizar `matrix` para el siguiente caso si el tamaño es suficiente, pero creo que *ofusca* la idea central del código, sin aportar nada relevante. Lo dejo a las ganas de investigar de cada uno.